# I have a c#.net dll with events , I want to use this event in delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, events, delegates

I have a **c#.net dll** with events.
I use it in C# like this:

```
  PcPos.CardSwiped += PosCardSwiped;
```

and declare a procedure and i can get data in it
but I want to **use this event** in **delphi**.

when i import dll in delphi create a **TLB file** with pas extension but i doon't know how to use it

Comment: Have you looked at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73219102/using-events-from-c-sharp-dll-in-delphi-com